# how to add a login/email page for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, email, google-chrome-extension

I am making my first chrome extension. Currently, it's very simple just to get a hang of everything. I am keeping track of all the links a user is clicking, and then at the end of the day I want to email the user a list of all the links. I am storing the links in a database called firebase.

My question is this: when the user installs my chrome extension, I want to have a page show up that asks for an email, this is the email that will be emailed the links at the end of the day. I am very confused as to where this page would be implemented within the extension, since I only want it to show up on installation of the extension. Right now I have an "inject" script that is a content script and a "background" script.

I'm not sure where to edit my manifest and what script to add. I think I should add something to the "Page_Action" of my manifest. Any help or examples as to how to do this would be appreciated! Thanks

Also, I don't necessarily want to use the email of the user logged in to chrome, a user should be able to enter any unrelated email.

Answer (score 1):

The idea to do this is as follows:

1. Create the page and scripts you need and put it into the extension folder.

   - Make sure it [obeys CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), e.g. no inline handlers, all code in a separate file.
   - Note that you can use any Chrome APIs as you would in a background page.
2. In your background page, you can listen to the [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) event.

   - Note that it will trigger for more than the initial install. A reasonable way to do that is to set some sort of flag once the registration is done - and check that flag. Note that using [`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) (requires `"storage"` permission) is preferable: then copies of your extension installed via Extension Sync won't bug the user again.
   - In case the user skips registration, but you need it done anyway, it might be useful to try to check registration at [`chrome.runtime.onStartup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) as well.
3. If the requisites are met, open the page with [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create).

   - Use [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) if you want a separate popup-like window)
4. In the page, don't forget to set the registration data so that it's not asked again.

Putting it all together:

```
// Possibly the same with onStartup event
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("registration", function(data) {
    if (!data.registration) {
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("register.html")
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And somewhere in  the code of registration page:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({registration: someData});
```